# Cannot send an empty message but its an embed object

Tags: discord.js

```
                                if (!user) { return message.edit(":x: Unknown user!") }
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("**Userinfo**")
                .setColor("#00D4FF")
                .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
                .setDescription("Username - **" + user.username + "**\nDiscrim - **"              + user.discriminator + "**\nID - **" + user.id +  "**\nStatus - **" + user.presence.status + "**\n")
                .setFooter({text: "Quelle: Discord"});
                //send the embed
                message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
```

Why am i getting a "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Version: "discord.js-selfbot-v13": "^2.15.0"

I already tried it without the array.

i want to send the Embed :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the `displayAvatarURL()` method within your `.setThumbnail()` which was introduced with discord.js v13 and above as far as I recall.

So your embed would become:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("**Userinfo**")
.setColor("#00D4FF")
.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
.setDescription("Username - **" + user.username + "**\nDiscrim - **"              + user.discriminator + "**\nID - **" + user.id +  "**\nStatus - **" + user.presence.status + "**\n")
.setFooter({text: "Quelle: Discord"});
```

This can be seen on the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/GuildMember:Class#displayAvatarURL), albeit this is for v14 but the core method remains the same for v13.